# How to send direct slack messages to users without a webhook?

Tags: curl, slack, slack-api, hipchat

I am migrating some code from hipchat to slack. There is one hipchat curl command I used to send dm's to users that I want to convert over to slack:

```
msg='hello world'

curl --fail -d "$(jq -c -n --arg msg "${msg}" '{"message_format": "text", "message": $msg}')" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json"  \
  -X POST "https://my.hipchat.server.com/v2/user/$USERS_EMAIL/message?auth_token=$HIPCHAT_TOKEN"
```

Lets say all I have is a [bot token](https://api.slack.com/docs/token-types#bot) and the email of the user account I want to send a message to (with no webhook setup).  How can I send a message to that user? What is the exact curl structure I would use?

Comment: This looks like you are asking us to do all the work for you. I am therefore voting to close. But to get you started: You want to use the API endpoint chat.postMessage for sending DMs. User ID as channel. Here is the docu: https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Savageman had it mostly correct.  The only difference is that you need to use `im.open`.  Here is my working code:

```
msg='the text yall want to send'
user_id="$(curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $SLACK_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  "https://slack.com/api/users.lookupByEmail?email=$EMAIL" | jq -r .user.id)"

channel_id="$(curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $SLACK_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  "https://slack.com/api/im.open?user=$user_id" | jq -r .channel.id)"

curl -X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer $SLACK_TOKEN" \
  -H 'Content-type: application/json' \
  --data "$(jq -c -n --arg msg "${msg}" --arg channel "${channel_id}" '{"channel":$channel,"text": $msg}')" \
  https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it in a single command.

1. Get the User ID using `users.lookupByEmail`
2. Make sure the DM is open using `dm.open` (this will also give you the channel ID for the direct message with that user)
3. Send the message with `chat.postMessage`